# How to overwrite SERVICE_NAME in generated grpc class

Tags: java, grpc, proto, protobuf-java

I have 2 different proto files with same package names and same message names, so when I try to compile them - there are conflicts

```
syntax = "proto3";

package foobar;

service API {
    rpc Foo (FooReq) returns (FooRsp);
}

message FooReq {}

message FooRsp {
    string Bar = 1;
}
```

```
syntax = "proto3";

package foobar;

service AnotherAPI {
    rpc Foo (FooReq) returns (FooRsp);
}

message FooReq {}

message FooRsp {
    string Bar = 1;
}
```

If I try to rename one of the packages to

```
package renamed.foobar;
```

SERVICE_NAME in generated AnotherAPIGrpc class becomes invalid

```
public static final String SERVICE_NAME = "renamed.foobar.AnotherAPI";
```

and I have error on trying to call method

`io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service renamed.foobar.AnotherAPI`

If I add different `option java_package` values for both protos, there are still errors like
`PROTOC FAILED: api1.proto:10:9: "foobar.FooReq" is already defined in file "api2.proto".`

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Did you try rebuilding the server as well? That would probably resolve the "unknown service" error. Another option would be to keep the service names as-is but rename the messages (not change the package).

Comment: I don't have a server. I'm a client for both services.

It works if I change service name in generated grpc class, but it's definitely not a good idea.

Comment: Well, the owner of these protos wrote them in a broken way. The protos need to be fixed by the owners. If there were different owners for the two services, then it was essential they coordinate or used different packages.

Comment: You should be able to add `option java_package` statements to each of the protos using different namespaces to disambiguate them with different generated namespaces. See [Packages](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/generated-code/#packages)

Comment: It doesn't help.
There are still errors: `PROTOC FAILED: api1.proto:10:9: "foobar.FooReq" is already defined in file "api2.proto".`